# Keras mixture of models

Tags: keras

Is it possible to implement MLP mixture of expert methodology in Keras?
Could you please guide me by a simple code in Keras for a binary problem with 2 experts.

It needs to define a cost function like this:

```python
g = gate.layers[-1].output
o1 = mlp1.layers[-1].output
o2 = mlp2.layers[-1].output

def ME_objective(y_true, y_pred):
    A = g[0] * T.exp(-0.5*T.sqr(y_true – o1))
    B = g[1] * T.exp(-0.5*T.sqr(y_true – o2))
    return -T.log((A+B).sum())  # cost
```

Comment: Hum, are you trying to train one classifier `g` whose task is to combine the outputs of two 'sub' classifiers `o1` and `o2` ?

Comment: Hi, I have 2 MLP experts with one neuron output (o1expert 1 output and o2 expert 2 output) and also 1 MLP gating network with two neuron outputs (g[0], g[1]). In forwarding pass, o1*g[0]+o2*g[1] is final output of the model. This model is trained end to end and the loss function is something like above. Can I implement this method by theano and keras?

Comment: MLP experts and MLP gate are deep models.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Model

You can definitely model such a structure in Keras, with [a merge layer](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#the-merge-layer), which enables you to combine different inputs.
Here is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that you'll hopefully be able to adapt to your structure

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.engine import Merge
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import keras.backend as K

xdim = 4
ydim = 1
gate = Sequential([Dense(2, input_dim=xdim)])
mlp1 = Sequential([Dense(1, input_dim=xdim)])
mlp2 = Sequential([Dense(1, input_dim=xdim)])


def merge_mode(branches):
    g, o1, o2 = branches
    # I'd have liked to write
    # return o1 * K.transpose(g[:, 0]) + o2 * K.transpose(g[:, 1])
    # but it doesn't work, and I don't know enough Keras to solve it
    return K.transpose(K.transpose(o1) * g[:, 0] + K.transpose(o2) * g[:, 1])


model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([gate, mlp1, mlp2], output_shape=(ydim,), mode=merge_mode))
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

train_size = 19
nb_inputs = 3  # one input tensor for each branch (g, o1, o2)
x_train = [np.random.random((train_size, xdim)) for _ in range(nb_inputs)]
y_train = np.random.random((train_size, ydim))
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

### Custom Objective

Here is an implementation of the objective you described. There are a few **mathematical concerns** to keep in mind though (see below).

```py
def me_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    g = gate.layers[-1].output
    o1 = mlp1.layers[-1].output
    o2 = mlp2.layers[-1].output
    A = g[:, 0] * K.transpose(K.exp(-0.5 * K.square(y_true - o1)))
    B = g[:, 1] * K.transpose(K.exp(-0.5 * K.square(y_true - o2)))
    return -K.log(K.sum(A+B))

# [...] edit the compile line from above example
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=me_loss)
```

### Some Math

Short version: somewhere in your model, I think there should be at least one constraint (maybe two):

> For any `x`, `sum(g(x)) = 1`
>
> For any `x`, `g0(x) > 0 and g1(x) > 0`  *# might not be strictly necessary*

**Domain study**

1. If `o1(x)` and `o2(x)` are infinitely **far** from `y`:

   - the exp term tends toward +0
   - `A -> B -> +-0`  depending on `g0(x)` and `g1(x)` signs
   - `cost -> +infinite` or `nan`
2. If `o1(x)` and `o2(x)` are infinitely **close** to `y`:

   - the exp term tends toward 1
   - `A -> g0(x)` and `B -> g1(x)`
   - `cost -> -log(sum(g(x)))`

The problem is that `log` is only defined on `]0, +inf[`. Which means that for the objective to be always defined, there needs to be a constraint somewhere ensuring `sum(A(x) + B(x)) > 0` for **any** `x`. A more restrictive version of that constraint would be (`g0(x) > 0` and `g1(x) > 0`).

**Convergence**

An even more important concern here is that this objective does not seem to be designed to converge towards 0. When `mlp1` and `mlp2` start predicting `y` correctly (case 2.), there is currently nothing preventing the optimizer to make `sum(g(x))` tend towards `+infinite`, to make `loss` tend towards `-inifinite`.

Ideally, we'd like `loss -> 0`, i.e. `sum(g(x)) -> 1`

Comment: Hi, my_mode fun generates the following error as you mentioned before it needs some debugging:

Comment: Exception: The Merge layer merge_1 has a callable `mode` argument, and we cannot infer its output shape because no `output_shape` argument was provided.Make sure to pass a shape tuple (or a callable) `output_shape` to Merge.

Comment: Edited my question with a working example. You might have to adapt it for it to work with your own 3 branches. At least as far as input dimensions are concerned ;) I might spend more time later on to try to implement your custom objective, I'll let you know

Comment: Objective done as well. Took me quite some time to write the maths concerns, but it was interesting :)

Comment: Ok, great job. It was so useful for me. Thank you Amaud.

Comment: Dear Amaud,
Hi,
In the previous question (Keras mixture of models), is it possible to learn each sub-model with a different cost function and different optimizer?

Comment: Yes in my opinion it would make more sense to train one classifier `g` whose task is to combine the outputs of two 'sub' classifiers `o1` and `o2`. Which means you need to create two Keras models (o1, o2) having their own loss, and train them independently on the same data. Then use their predictions (outputs) as input data to train a third model (g). You might also want to provide the original input (`x_train`) to `g` to give it more context.

Comment: So `g` can be implemented as a [Multi-input model](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models). Otherwise you can also concatenate the outputs of `o1` and `o2` (with maybe `x_train` as I said) into a single vector / matrix and use a standard input for `g`